# Why do we use "au" and "aux" before country names?

Tags: prépositions, indications-de-lieu, contractions

I saw that “au” comes before “Portugal”. But, “au” means “the”, doesn't it? Should then “the” come before “Portugal”?

Also, when do we use “aux”?

Comment: Back ticks are meant to be used around (computer) code. You should not use them in other context — especially as they can make reading pages harder for some people. There are few reasons to use it on the French stack exchange.

Comment: Also, no need to write thanks. They don’t really match the “question/answers” format of stack exchange. Thank people answering by up voting their answers.

Answer (score 12):

“*Au*” does **not** mean “the”*. “*Le*” (or “*la*”, or “*l’*”, or “*les*”) means “the”. “*Au*” is the [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)) of *“<strike>*à le*</strike>” (*“<strike>*à le*</strike>” is grammatically incorrect). Similarly, “*aux*” is the contraction of *“<strike>à les</strike>”.

In French, the name of a country is indeed preceded by an article. We say “*la France,  le Portugal, l’Allemagne, les Pays-Bas*”. Thus, whenever “le Portugal” is preceded by “*à*” (which has [various meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0#French)), it becomes “au Portugal”; similarly, when “les Pays-Bas” is preceded by “à”, it becomes “aux Pays-Bas”.

Note, however, that when countries which are *feminine*<sup>1</sup> and *singular* are preceded by “*à*”, it becomes “*en*”: “*en France, en Allemagne*”. This only occurs with names of countries or regions.

---

1. Or masculine but begin with a vowel sound.

Comment: Note that *aux* is also used before some féminines including a definite plural (aux Antilles) while some masculines starting with a vowel take *en*...

Comment: I can't think of any "masculine" country beginning with an vowel. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: Afghanistan, Ouzbékistan, Israel,...